# Imploding array giving extra symbols in PHP

Tags: php

I am having an array which is also having some blank space and because of those blank spaces, when I imploding the array it is giving me extra comma. Please take a look at my code and suggest me how can I get rid of it.

```html
$xrd = implode(',', $admin_array);}

//Output is ,12,62,,76,,,45,,
//Output should be 12,62,76,45
```

Comment: Could you please add little bit more code what elments are in $admin_array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the blank elements before imploding.

```
$xrd = implode(',', array_filter($admin_array));
```

If the array could contain the string `0`, you'll need to be more specific:

```
$xrd = implode(',', array_filter($admin_array, function($x) { return $x !== ""; });
```

Comment: Just be careful as this will remove `0` as well which maybe you want to keep.